# Express.js : What is the difference between res.attachment and res.download?

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference between `res.attachment` and `res.download` and when to use which I am bit confused. In my case, I send my form data to the server as a JSON which will create a file out of it and respond with a download link. Which among the two: `res.attachment` and `res.download` should I use?

Answer (score 18):

The `res.attachment` "Sets the HTTP response Content-Disposition header field to “attachment”."

This essentially says, 'Hey, this file should be viewed as an attachment, not a webpage.'

Whereas the `res.download` "Transfers the file at path as an “attachment”. Typically, browsers will prompt the user for download."

Find more about each [HERE](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download)

Comment: Ok..  So if I do res.attachment I need to separately do a response.sendfile to actually send a file. But the same is not required of res.download.

Comment: Do res.attachment(filename.zip) create a file or a write stream?

Comment: @NeerajSewani It is NOT clear exactly what is the difference between the two. In both cases, the response is a file sent back to the client! I read the documentation and I do not see clear differences except res.download() provide call back function for error handling. Are there any other differences between the two?

Comment: There are a few key differences between the two. As x7R5fQ points out, `.download` has a `callback` param for error handling as well as an `options` param, which the contents get passed through to the `.sendFile()` method if needed. As for `.attachment()`, this method DOES return an Object whereas `.download()` does not have a return value.